# App Engine Flex high latency and delay in start instances

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I have a problem with the start of new instances. My system has a large flow, where it goes down and up quickly. As the flow rises fast, the survey of instances is unable to keep up, thus causing the slowness. After a while it stabilizes, but until then it causes high latency. Can anyone help?

My app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 2
  max_num_instances: 12
  cool_down_period_sec: 120
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.2
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 8
```

Through the app engine panel, my average CPU usage is 20% and 8Gb memory.
I don't understand why it is slow if the machine doesn't work to the limit.
Thanks!

Comment: Details. Where are they? Stating `high latency` and `delay in start` means nothing. Specify numbers and not relative terms. There are three different types of app starts: first starts, cold starts, and warm starts. What are these numbers for your deployment? Use Stackdriver to collect metrics.

Comment: While waiting for your update, you may want to review the [2 types](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) of App Engine environments. First understand how Flex [would scale up your instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/flexible-for-standard-users#scaling_characteristics) and how Standard could be a better option if you want an instance that scales very quickly.